# Why does DbContext in EF Core return changed entity after Transaction Rollback

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I want to verify that Transaction is rolled back on the case of an exception. The below method can potentially throw an exception.

```
// method Checkout(user, reduceMoney, addBill)
using (var transaction = _botContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        await FirstDbUpdate(user, reduceMoney);
        await SecondDbUpdate(user, addBill); // potential exception

        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

To verify **the rollback** I wrote this test:

```
[Test]
public async Task Test_TransactionFail_RevertedUserUpdate()
{
    // Arrange user{budget: 10}
    var user = await _userRepository.GetByName("John Doe");
    var reduceMoney = 10m;

    // Act - null causes an exception
    await _service.Checkout(user, reduceMoney, null);  

    // Assert
    var userRetrieved = await _userRepository.GetByName("John Doe");
    Assert.AreEqual(10, userRetrieved.Budget);
}
```

Assertion fails because the user has a budget of 0. i.e. it looks like the change was persisted, but in reality, it is not (which is the correct behavior).

So the question is why does DbContext return **the not persisted data**, and where does it get it from? Shouldn't the rollback have removed them?

Comment: integration tests? are you going into the actual database or this is some sort of a mock for your DbContext? do you see the same behaviour outside of your test?

Comment: Because you are in the some context instance, the query in Assert will load from the same instance instead to have a direct query to your database. Try with other instance or reload it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry.reload?view=efcore-2.0

Comment: @ocrenaka that was the solution I just replaced the second query with reloading call. Can you please comment so I can mark it as the solution?

Comment: Sure @rinormaloku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are in the some context instance, the query in Assert will load from the same instance instead to have a direct query to your database.

Try with other instance or reload it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry.reload?view=efcore-2.0

Comment: It is a bit weird that changes in the ChangeTracked are not reverted inside a Transaction